# Let $\{P_n\}$ uniformly converge to $f$ on $T$. prove that exists analytic and continuous $F$ on $\bar{D}$ such that $F \equiv f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{P_n\}$ be a series of polynomials which uniformly converges on the unit circle $ T  = \{|z| = 1\}$ to $f$.

prove there exists $F$ such that $F$ is analytic in the unit disk $D$ and continuous in the closed unit disk $\bar{D}$ such that $F \equiv f$ on $T$.

I think that f must by analytic on $T$ so the radius of convergence is at least 1.
so f actually qualifies to be F. but I'm not sure I'm correct?

Comment: $f$ does not qualify because $f$ is not defined on $\overline D$...

Comment: why is it not defined? f is defined on T, and we can write it as a power series, with a radius of convergence = 1

Comment: You are correct in a sense. $f$ is only defined on $T$. However, you can take the power series of $f$ and that power series converges to some function on $D$. The function cannot be $f$ because it has a different domain, however, it is equal to $f$ on $T$.

Comment: can you please help how do i prove that f must be analytic on T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction of $P_n$ to $T$ converges uniformly, so $(P_n|_T)$ is uniformly Cauchy on $T$. By the maximum modulus principle, $(P_n)$ is also uniformly Cauchy on $\bar D$, and thus converges uniformly to some (continuous) function $F$ on $\bar D$.

On the other hand, Morera's theorem shows that a uniform limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, so in fact $F$ is holomorphic on $D$.